# How to close existing connection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I found that some connection got unclosed after the execution of command from Mysql server.

How can I configure my Mysql server so that I can close them all after executing a command?

Comment: What command do you execute?  Is it a piece of code you wrote?  You need to add more info, this is way to vague.

Answer (score 4):

if you can get the process_id inside mysql you can kill the process. Killing any process should work (though it will create a new connection next time you send a command).

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST; -- or SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
mysql> KILL process_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) variable to something soon enough, for example 30 seconds

Comment: Just don't have a query that can take longer than 30 secs.